# Module not found: Can't resolve './firebase-config.json'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, firebase, web

I am trying to run react based application on http://localhost:3000/. I am getting above mentioned error on my chrome. I tried my end to google issue but not able to figured out the problem.
node version 16.15
firebase version 10.8.0

I am completely new to firebase so please help me.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import 'firebase/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

import StyledFirebaseAuth from 'react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth';
const firebaseConfig = require('./firebase-config.json');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think **.** is your public folder, since index.html is there.

You should try to import it as **../firebase-config.json**, where **..** takes you to the root of the project.